# Hide a div when a data-attribute as value of 0

Tags: javascript, html

I have some buttons with data-attibutes that are passing to html when they are clicked.
I'm not beeing able to hide the div of .discounts when the value inserted on the data-attibute is equal to 0. Here is my code:

```js
var discounters = document.querySelectorAll(".discount__Topics");

discounters.forEach((index) => {

    var buttons = index.querySelectorAll(".form-button");

    buttons.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function(){    
            var discount = getDiscount(this);
            let span = index.querySelector('.discount-amount')
            span.innerHTML = '<strong>' + discount+ '</strong>'
        });
    });

    function getDiscount(clicked_element) {
        var val = clicked_element.getAttribute("data-discount");  
        return val;
    }

});
```

```css
.discount__Topics {
margin-bottom:20px;
}

.discounts {
background-color: red;
color: white;
display: inline-flex;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="discount__Topics">
<div class="discounts"><strong class="discount-amount">38</strong>%</div>

<div class="offers"> 
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="38">Offer 1</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="0">Offer 2</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="22">Offer 3</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="88">Offer 4</button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="discount__Topics">
<div class="discounts"><strong class="discount-amount">12</strong>%</div>

<div class="offers"> 
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="12">Offer 1</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="32">Offer 2</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="0">Offer 3</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="55">Offer 4</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope someone can help me.
Many thanks

Comment: Can be done using a CSS selector or `button[data-discount="0"]`.

Comment: After the var discount, you can check there if the value returned in discount variable is 0. If it is, then you can change the style to display : none and if not proceed your way as you were.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use JavaScript to hide an element with a specific data attribute value. You can just use a [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```css
[data-discount='0'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
[data-discount='0'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p data-discount="38">Attribute is equal to 38</p>
<p data-discount="0"> Attribute is equal to 0 </p>
<p data-discount="12">Attribute is equal to 12</p>
<p data-discount="7"> Attribute is equal to 7 </p>
```

Comment: I don't want to hide the button but the .discounts div

Comment: Are you adding the data attribute to the discounts div? If so, you can just change the selector to `.discounts[data-discounts="0"]`. If you're not adding the data attribute to the discounts div, I would reword your question to say "...value inserted *from* the..."

Answer (score 0):

To hide an element, you can simply do : `element.style.display = "none"`.

So just add a condition to your JS where `discount == 0` and then get the element by a query selector for your `.discounts` to finally change it's display style :)

Hope it helps ! Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

This code does the work for you (it is working for the first span, just do it in the same way for the other span too):

```js
var discounters = document.querySelectorAll(".discount__Topics");

discounters.forEach((index) => {

    var buttons = index.querySelectorAll(".form-button");

    buttons.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function(){    
            var discount = getDiscount(this);
            let span = index.querySelector('.discount-amount')
            if (discount!=0){  
                 document.getElementById("firstDiscount").style.display = "inline-flex"
                 span.innerHTML = '<strong>' + discount+ '</strong>'
               }else{
                   
                 document.getElementById("firstDiscount").style.display = "none"
               }
            });
    });

    function getDiscount(clicked_element) {
        var val = clicked_element.getAttribute("data-discount");  
        return val;
    }

});
```

```css
.discount__Topics {
margin-bottom:20px;
}

.discounts {
background-color: red;
color: white;
display: inline-flex;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="discount__Topics">
<div id="firstDiscount" class="discounts"><strong class="discount-amount">38</strong>%</div>

<div class="offers"> 
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="38">Offer 1</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="0">Offer 2</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="22">Offer 3</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="88">Offer 4</button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="discount__Topics">
<div id="secondDiscount" class="discounts"><strong class="discount-amount">12</strong>%</div>

<div class="offers"> 
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="12">Offer 1</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="32">Offer 2</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="0">Offer 3</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="55">Offer 4</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it with:

```js
var discounters = document.querySelectorAll(".discount__Topics");

discounters.forEach((index) => {

    var buttons = index.querySelectorAll(".form-button");

    buttons.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function(){    
            var discount = getDiscount(this);
            let span = index.querySelector('.discount-amount')
            span.innerHTML = '<strong>' + discount+ '</strong>'
              if (discount !=0){  
                   index.querySelector(".discounts").style.display = "inline-flex"
                 } else {
                   index.querySelector(".discounts").style.display = "none"
              }
            });
    });

    function getDiscount(clicked_element) {
        var val = clicked_element.getAttribute("data-discount");  
        return val;
    }

});
```

```css
.discount__Topics {
margin-bottom:20px;
}

.discounts {
background-color: red;
color: white;
display: inline-flex;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="discount__Topics">
<div class="discounts"><strong class="discount-amount">38</strong>%</div>

<div class="offers"> 
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="38">Offer 1</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="0">Offer 2</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="22">Offer 3</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="88">Offer 4</button>
</div>
</div>

<div class="discount__Topics">
<div class="discounts"><strong class="discount-amount">12</strong>%</div>

<div class="offers"> 
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="12">Offer 1</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="32">Offer 2</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="0">Offer 3</button>
  <button class="form-button" data-discount="55">Offer 4</button>
</div>
</div>
```